# Which tab controller is the one being picked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller with five buttons. That controller has a tab view controller.

The tab view controller should behave differently depending on the tab being pressed.

For example, if the tab is "location", then the displayed data should be sorted based on location. If the tab is "alphabet", then the view should be sorted based on the alphabet.

I have this code in the view controller

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [BNUtilitiesQuick parseXMLFileAtURL:@"http://example.com/BusinessSerialized.xml"];
    [BNUtilitiesQuick UtilitiesQuick].BizsToDisplay = [BNUtilitiesQuick searchObjectsInContext:@"Business" :nil :@"Title" :YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self tabBarController]);
    if ([[self tabBarController]selectedIndex]==0)
    {
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",[[self tabBarController] selectedIndex]);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

That `[[self tabBarController] selectedIndex]` works, except for one problem. Rather than giving the current selected index, it's the previous index.

Say I am now selecting tab 0, and I click tab 4; that `NSLog()` will display 0.

How can I solve this? I want to know the tab being pressed.

Comment: If you're using a tab bar controller, you generally don't need to worry about which tab was selected -- it's the tab controller's job to display the view of the controller that corresponds to the selected tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using this delegate method you will be getting your selected index:

```
# enter code here
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"sff %d",tabBarController.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: So the delegate should be the files' owner of the tabController

Comment: What protocol does that thing is defined?